# Enforce two types in Map value - Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a situation, I need to use `Map`, and put `String` as key and `String` or `Long` as value.

As they don't fall into same hierarchy, I think I can't use wildcards.

So is there any way to enforce compiler to accept either `String` or `Long` as value or I will have to go with `Map` without **generics**.

Comment: Would it be a problem to use String.valueof(T) ? As it can parse longs into strings as well.

Comment: You can use map like this Map<String,Object>

Comment: U can use ```Map<String, Object>```

Comment: What is the functionality? Maybe you can store everything in String?

Comment: You should create your own class then. StringOrLong.

Comment: I think using <String, String> would be fine workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions either use `Map<String, Object>`or create a class like

```
public class DualValue {
    private final String stringValue;
    private final Long   longValue;

    public DualValue(final String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
        this.longValue = null;
    }

    public DualValue(final Long longValue) {
        this.stringValue = null;
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public Long getLongValue() {
        return longValue;
    }

    public boolean isString() {
        return stringValue != null;
    }

    public boolean isLong() {
        return longValue != null;
    }

    // next two are optional but should be implemented,
    // if you ever want to use this class as key of a Map

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        DualValue dualValue = (DualValue) o;

        if (longValue != null ? !longValue.equals(dualValue.longValue) : dualValue.longValue != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (stringValue != null ? !stringValue.equals(dualValue.stringValue) : dualValue.stringValue != null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = stringValue != null ? stringValue.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (longValue != null ? longValue.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and use `Map<String, DualValue>`. You are right that the compiler is not able to merge two destinct class-hirachies with a pure genric approach in another way than using `Object` which is common parent to every Java class. Even if it could you would probably have to check by using `value instanceof String` or `value instanceof Long` and cast to one of those if you would want to call any functions on the value not present in `Object`.

Comment: If you want to use it as a Map key you should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: @PeterBagyinszki added basic equals and hashCode though OP only wanted to use it as value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just have to store an Object, which is pretty much the same as storing without generics (except of course the String key will still be checked, and you won't get compiler warnings).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your long to a string and then you can have a map of `<String,String>`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Object, since you can end up with unwanted data in that list. Having only String objects, you can enforce a better security